# nodejs express error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, socket.io

I am using `socket.io` with `nodejs` and trying to get `socketio` instance in one of the class's methods.

Project folder structure:

[image]

I have following code:

`app.ts`:

```
class App  {
  public app: express.Application;
  private PORT: number;
  private dbUrl = DB_URL as string;
  public IO = null;

  constructor(routes: any, port: any) {
    this.app = express();
    this.config();      
  }

  public listen = (): void => {
      const server = this.app.listen(this.PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Server is running on port ${this.PORT}`);
      });
      const io = socket(server);
      this.IO = io; <-- IO

  };
}

export default App;
```

`server.ts`

```
import App from "./app";

import Auth from "./Route/Auth";
import TwitterFeed from './Route/TwitterFeed';
import EconomicFeed from './Route/EconomicFeed';
require("dotenv").config();

const { PORT } = process.env;
const app = new App([new Auth(), new TwitterFeed(), new EconomicFeed()], PORT);
app.listen();
export default app; <-- export app here
```

`TwitterFeed`:

```
import app from '../../server';
class TwitterFeed {
    .
    .
    .
    private streamPublicTweets = (request:Request, response:Response)=>{      
        // establish socket connection
        console.log('app', app.IO); <-- this is displayed with no error
        const io = app.IO 
        io.on('connection', (socket: any) => {
          console.log('socket connected');
          streamTweets(this.T, socket)
        });    
    }
}
```

In `TwitterFeed` class, I am trying to access `app` import in one of the methods.
In console there is the output with no error:
[image]

But in line `io.on()` I get this error:
[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Really important here that you tag the question with typescript because this is likely more of a typescript problem than a javascript one.

Comment: @JamesM.Lay thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: You're initializing app.IO as null. Typescript isn't sure if it has been changed yet.

Comment: ^ willing to bet this is your problem $$

Comment: just switched to typescript and totally new. how do I fix this?

Comment: You probably just need to check if io is null before calling `io.on...`.  Something like `if (io !== null) { io.on('connection'...) }`

Comment: Just write `const io = app.IO!` or even give a type annotation on `listen(): App & { io: IO } { …; return this; }` then write `default export app.listen()`